# Is there a way to prevent the user from submitting form before s/he has at least moved the slider (input type = range)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a slider in my html form like this. It is for an online experiment. I have already set it to be required, but the thing is I wanna make sure the user has manipulated the slider in any way before submitting (i.e., click it at least). Because the slider comes at 50% position chose already by default, the user could just click "OK" without actually thinking about the answer. In this way, I could behaviorally force them to click it at least and make some reflections.

I've done Googling and didn't find any solutions on this.

```
<form id="q-familiarity">
  <label for="fam slider">How well are you familiar with this item ?   </label><br>
  <input name="fam slider" type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50"  step="0.5" class="slider" id="fam-slider" required>
  <button type="submit" form="q-familiarity">OK</button>
<form>
```

How could I implement a mechanism, where user has to at least click the slider once to "activate" the OK button (perhaps also OK goes from grey to black to indicate the change)?

I would prefer the solution to be html and css based, with as little js as possible. (I learned html and css by myself for the experiment and don't know any js) But I would guess js has to be used in the solution, which is ok.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest to disable the submit button by default and enable only if the user interacts with the input, like so

> [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OdRpeo)

```
<form>
  <label for="fam slider">How well are you familiar with this item ? </label><br>
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" step="0.5"  id="fam-slider" required>
  <button type="submit" id="submit-btt" disabled="disabled">OK</button>
<form>
```

Js

```
let slider = document.getElementById('fam-slider');
let button = document.getElementById('submit-btt');
slider.addEventListener('input', () => {
  button.removeAttribute('disabled');
})
```

At the `input` event on the slider remove the `disabled` attribute on the submit button.

I've used the `input` event instead of the `change` event because it is triggered as soon as the user drags the slider control, and allows the user to also choose the starting value (if he wants to)

Comment: could you please explain your code to FinnHusky? also, remember he asked for javascript not for jquery. He dont know about jquery and even javascript but he can understand javascript for some extent.

Comment: @UmerHayyat where do you see jQuery? and why spamming answers with that comment?

Comment: @UmerHayyat this is actually vanilla Javascript.

Comment: there is not only jquery point mentioned in my comment, code explanation?

Comment: I've inserted the explanation needed. I don't like to just write "try this", like other people does in other answers.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It works well and I could understand at least the idea of the JS involved.

Answer (score 2):

Well, unfortunately you need to use JS anyway to do it. If I have understood correctly, you're looking for a simple **change event**.

```js
var slider = document.getElementById( 'fam-slider' );
var submit = document.getElementById( 'submit' );
slider.addEventListener( 'change', function() {
submit.disabled = false;
});
```

```html
<form id="q-familiarity">
  <label for="fam slider">How well are you familiar with this item ?   </label><br>
  <input name="fam slider" type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50"  step="0.5" class="slider" id="fam-slider" required>
  <button id="submit" type="submit" form="q-familiarity" disabled>OK</button>
<form>
```

Comment: could you please explain your code to FinnHusky? also, remember he asked for javascript not for jquery. He dont know about jquery and even javascript but he can understand javascript for some extent.

Comment: Thank you. I could see that this solution has the same idea as the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the slider was changed or clicked and set a validation variable. Then on submit check your "valid" flag:

```js
var valid = false;

$("input.slider").on("change click", function(){
  valid = true;
});

$("#submit").click(function(){
  if (!valid){
    // do your logic here
    console.log("not valid");
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="q-familiarity">
  <label for="fam slider">How well are you familiar with this item ?   </label><br>
  <input name="fam slider" type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50"  step="0.5" class="slider" id="fam-slider" required>
  <button id="submit" type="submit" form="q-familiarity">OK</button>
<form>
```

Comment: could you please explain your code to FinnHusky? also, remember he asked for javascript not for jquery. He dont know about jquery and even javascript but he can understand javascript for some extent.

Comment: My answer has an explanation. In my opinion it would be much easier to understand a jquery code than a vanilla js with a lot of boilerplate code

Comment: It seems to be a good solution, but I could see that this script uses some remote resource, which might be unstable in future use. And for me personally, it is less readable than JS provided in the first two answers. Thank you anyways!

Comment: The link is to JQuery, it's very common to use that link so that the code uses JQuery will work in the snippet. Stackoverflow provides a select box to include it - and multiple JS libraries as well...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a jQuery solution for you if you prefer it over vanilla JS. The button is by default disabled, but as soon as you change the slider it becomes active.

```js
$('#slider').change(function() {
    $("#submitbutton").prop("disabled", false);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="q-familiarity">
  <label for="fam slider">How well are you familiar with this item ?   </label><br>
  <input id='slider' name="fam slider" type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50"  step="0.5" class="slider" id="fam-slider" required>
  <button id= "submitbutton" type="submit" disabled='true' form="q-familiarity">OK</button>
<form>
```

Comment: could you please explain your code to FinnHusky? also, remember he asked for javascript not for jquery. He dont know about jquery and even javascript but he can understand javascript for some extent.

Comment: Thank you. It seems to be a good solution, but I could see that this script uses some remote resource, which might be unstable in future use.